# How to make my ng-if stop showing after function success

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ng-if

I want my `ng-if="AddEmp"` to go false after my `ng-click` function has succeeded so the content in the `ng-if` doesn't show any longer, but I can't seem to make it happen.

I use the `ng-if` since I want the content in the form not to show the next time the form is visible. I always want it to be blank from the start.

How do I make the `ng-if="AddEmp"` disappear after this function has succeeded?

```
UserRegistration = function (Role, Id, Gender, Firstnamn, Lastnamn, DateOfBirth, phone, ClassId)
```

Here is my code:

Entire pages :

```js
angular.module('App')
.controller('SchoolAdminController',
['$scope', '$http', '$location', 'getAllRolesFactory', 'checkUserRolesFactory', 'userRegistrationFactory', 'getAllClassesFactory',
function ($scope, $http, $location, getAllRolesFactory, checkUserRolesFactory, userRegistrationFactory, getAllClassesFactory)
{
    var vm = this;
    vm.allRoles;
    vm.userWithRoles;
    vm.userWithoutRoles;
    vm.noUsersFound;
    vm.allClasses;

    getAllRolesFactory.get().then(function (response) {
        vm.allRoles = JSON.parse('[' + response.data + ']');
    });
 
    vm.AddUser = function ()
    {
        $location.path('/Register');
    }
    vm.EditEmployee = function () {
        $location.path('/SchoolAdmin/EditEmployee');
    }

    vm.UserWithoutRoles = function () {
        checkUserRolesFactory.get(0).then(function (response) {
            vm.userWithoutRoles = JSON.parse('[' + response.data + ']');
            if (vm.userWithoutRoles.length < 1) {
                vm.noUsersFound = 'Inga användare finns att hantera';
            }

        });
        vm.GetAllClasses();
    }
    vm.UserWithRoles = function () {
        checkUserRolesFactory.get(1).then(function (response) {
            vm.userWithRoles = JSON.parse('[' + response.data + ']');
            console.log(vm.userWithRoles);
        });
    }
    vm.UserRegistration = function (Role, Id, Gender, Firstnamn, Lastnamn, DateOfBirth, phone, ClassId) {
        vm.registerUserInfo = [];
        vm.roleInfo = [];
        vm.registerUserInfo.push({
            Firstname: Firstnamn,
            Lastname: Lastnamn,
            DateOfBirth: DateOfBirth,
            Gender: Gender,
            UserId: Id,
            ClassId: ClassId,
        })
        vm.roleInfo.push({
            Role : Role,
        })
        console.log(vm.registerUserInfo);
        userRegistrationFactory.register(vm.registerUserInfo, Role).then(function (response) {
            $scope.AddEmp = false;
            console.log(vm.AddEmp);
            console.log("Hello my name is linsey lohan");
        });
    }
    vm.GetAllClasses = function () {
        getAllClassesFactory.get().then(function (response) {
            console.log(vm.allClasses);
            vm.allClasses = JSON.parse('[' + response.data + ']');
            console.log(vm.allClasses);

        })
    }
}]);
```

```html
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "EditEmployee";
}


<div ng-controller="SchoolAdminController as SchoolAdmCtrl">
    
    <div class="col-md-8 gradeSelect" ng-click="SchoolAdmCtrl.UserWithRoles(); editEmp = ! editEmp; AddEmp = false" id="editEmp">
        <a><h1>Klicka här redigera Anställd:</h1></a>

    </div>
        <div class="col-md-8 gradeSelect" ng-if="editEmp">
            <div>
                @*TODO: Fixa, ta bort Gradeselect på hela formuläret.
                        En admin ska inte redigera sigsjälv på samma sätt som andra users i systemet.
                    *@

                <form name="EditEmpForm">

                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Välj anställd för hantering</legend>

                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Välj roll att tilldela användare<br />
                                    <select ng-model="SelectRole" name="SelectRole_field" ng-options="role as role for role in SchoolAdmCtrl.allRoles" required></select>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.SelectRole_field.$error.required">Välj roll</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Välj anställd
                                    <select ng-model="selectUserWith" name="SelectUserWith_field"
                                            ng-options=" user as user.Email for user in SchoolAdmCtrl.userWithRoles | filter : {Role : SelectRole}" required></select>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.SelectUserWith_field.$error.required">Välj användare</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Sök på person<br />
                                    <input ng-model="Sokperson" type="text" />
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <legend>Redigera anställd</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Kön<br />
                                    <select ng-model="Kon" name="Kon_field" required>
                                        <option>Female</option>
                                        <option>Male</option>
                                    </select>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Kon_field.$error.required">Välj kön</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>

                                <label>
                                    Förnamn<br />
                                    <input ng-model="Fornamn" name="Fornamn_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" />
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Fornamn_field.$error.minlength">För kort!</span>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Fornamn_field.$error.maxlength">För långt!</span>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Fornamn_field.$error.pattern"> A-Z -'!</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Efternamn<br />
                                    <input ng-model="Efternamn" name="Efternamn_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" />
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Efternamn_field.$error.minlength">För kort!</span>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Efternamn_field.$error.maxlength">För långt!</span>
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Efternamn_field.$error.pattern"> A-Z -'!</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Personnummer<br />
                                    <input ng-model="Personnummer" name="Personnummer_field" type="text" placeholder="ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/" required />
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Personnummer_field.$error.pattern">Följ "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD".</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Telefonnummer<br />
                                    <input ng-model="Telefon" name="Telefon_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="9" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/" />
                                    <span style="color:red" ng-show="EditEmpForm.Telefon_field.$error.pattern">Felaktigt telefonformat.</span>
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset ng-if="SelectRole=='Guardian'">
                        <legend>Redigera arbetsuppgifter</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>Välj Barn</label>
                                <select ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
                            </li> @* lägga till knapp för att kunna lägga till flera barn*@
                            <li>
                                <label>Sök barn</label>
                                <input type="text" requried />
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset ng-if="SelectRole=='Student'">
                        <legend>Redigera arbetsuppgifter</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>Välj klass</label>
                                <select ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Sök på klassnamn</label>
                                <input type="text" required />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Förmyndare 1
                                    <input type="text" required />
                                </label>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>
                                    Förmyndare 2
                                    <input type="text" required />
                                </label>
                            </li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset ng-if="SelectRole=='Teacher'">
                        <legend>Redigera arbetsuppgifter</legend>
                        <ol>
                            <li>
                                <label>Välj klass</label>
                                <select ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Sök på klassnamn</label>
                                <input type="text" required />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Aktuella klasser för anställd</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>klass 1 test</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>klass 2 test</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label> Välj Kurs</label>
                                <select ng-model="selectedItem"></select>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Sök på kursnamn</label>
                                <input type="text" required />
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <label>Aktuella kurser för anställd</label>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>kurs 1 test</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <label>kurs 2 test</label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" />
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                        </ol>
                    </fieldset>

                    <fieldset>
                        <button type=submit>Spara ändringar</button>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div class="col-md-8 gradeSelect" ng-click="SchoolAdmCtrl.UserWithoutRoles(); SchoolAdmCtrl.GetAllClasses(); AddEmp = ! AddEmp; editEmp = false" id="AddEmp">
        <a><h1>Klicka här för att hantera anställda som ännu inte har roller i systemet</h1></a>
    </div>
    {{AddEmp}}
    <div class="col-md-8 gradeSelect" ng-if="AddEmp">
        <div>
           
            <h1 style="color:red">{{SchoolAdmCtrl.noUsersFound}}</h1>
            <form name="AddEmpForm" ng-if="SchoolAdmCtrl.noUsersFound !=''">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Välj anställd för hantering</legend>

                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Välj roll att tilldela användare<br />
                                <select ng-model="SelectRole2" name="SelectRole2_field" ng-options="role as role for role in SchoolAdmCtrl.allRoles" required></select>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.SelectRole2_field.$error.required">Välj roll</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Hantera anställda som ännu inte har roller i systemet<br />
                                <select ng-model="selectUserWithout2" name="SelectUserWithout2_field"
                                        ng-options="user as user.Email for user in SchoolAdmCtrl.userWithoutRoles | filter : Sokperson2"
                                        required></select>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.SelectUserWithout2_field.$error.required">Välj användare</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Sök på person<br />
                                <input ng-model="Sokperson2" type="text" />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Redigera anställd</legend>
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Kön<br />
                                <select ng-model="Kon2" name="Kon2_field" required>
                                    <option>Female</option>
                                    <option>Male</option>
                                </select>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Kon2_field.$error.required">Välj kön</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>

                            <label>
                                Förnamn<br />
                                <input ng-model="Fornamn2" name="Fornamn2_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" />
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.minlength">För kort!</span>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.maxlength">För långt!</span>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.pattern"> A-Z -'!</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Efternamn<br />
                                <input ng-model="Efternamn2" name="Efternamn2_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="2" ng-maxlength="20" ng-pattern="/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/i" />
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.minlength">För kort!</span>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.maxlength">För långt!</span>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.pattern"> A-Z -'!</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Personnummer<br />
                                <input ng-model="Personnummer2" name="Personnummer2_field" type="text" placeholder="ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="10" ng-pattern="/^((\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4}))$/" required />
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Personnummer2_field.$error.pattern">Följ "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD".</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Telefonnummer<br />
                                <input ng-model="Telefon2" name="Telefon2_field" type="text" required ng-minlength="9" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/\(?([0-9]{3})\)?([ .-]?)([0-9]{3})\2([0-9]{4})/" />
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.Telefon2_field.$error.pattern">Felaktigt telefonformat.</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset ng-if="SelectRole2=='Student'">
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Välj klass för elev<br />
                                <select ng-model="$parent.selectClass2" name="selectClass2_field" ng-options="klass as klass.Name for klass in SchoolAdmCtrl.allClasses" required></select>
                                <span style="color:red" ng-show="AddEmpForm.selectRole2_field.$error.required">Välj roll</span>
                            </label>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>
                                Sök på klass<br />
                                <input ng-model="Sokklass2" type="text" />
                            </label>
                        </li>
                    </ol>

                </fieldset>
                <button type="submit"
                        ng-disabled="
                            AddEmpForm.SelectRole2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.SelectUserWithout2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.Kon2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.minlength || AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.maxlength || AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.pattern || AddEmpForm.Fornamn2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.minlength || AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.maxlength || AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.pattern && AddEmpForm.Efternamn2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.Personnummer2_field.$error.pattern || AddEmpForm.Personnummer2_field.$error.required ||
                            AddEmpForm.Telefon2_field.$error.pattern || AddEmpForm.Telefon2_field.$error.required"
                        ng-click="SchoolAdmCtrl.UserRegistration(SelectRole2, selectUserWithout2.Id, Kon2, Fornamn2, Efternamn2, Personnummer2, Telefon2, selectClass2.Id)">
                    Spara ändringar
                </button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

 </div>
```

Comment: Instead of `vm.AddEmp = false;` have you tried `$scope.AddEmp = false;`?

Comment: oh sorry. ive used the .. "var vm = this;" instead of using $scope.. so all $scope is used with vm instead.

Comment: Where are you doing that? I don't see it in the posted code.  Also, can you humor me and try it? Also also, I don't see where a lot of the model variables you're referencing in your html are defined...

Comment: hmm wierd it did work with $scope instead of vm . even though i always use vm instead of $scope in my controller. imma add both of the entire pages and maybe u can tell me why it didnt work this time?.

Comment: `var vm = this;` is considered a bad practice. Just use `$scope` instead. Also, `this` can represent something different from time to time. It doesn't always have to represent `$scope`. That's what `$scope` is there for.

Comment: I'm going to post an answer with a few general angular things that need to be cleaned up. One of them was the $scope vs vm thing.

Comment: well ive been using this https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#controllers

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things wrong that stand out.

1. You're making direct calls to class methods like so: `SchoolAdmCtrl.UserWithRoles()`. You should really be assigning those methods to your scope in your controller, like this:

   ```
   $scope.UserWithRoles = function(){ ... }
   ```

Then you'll just need to call UserWithRoles(); like this:

```
    ng-click="UserWithRoles();"
```

2. You're storing all of your data on that class. This *might* work just for this example, but like Guido Bouman said above, you should be storing it all on $scope. You're very likely to get undesired behavior if you have another instance of this controller I'd bet. Also, when you do this, you'll need to change all of your `vm.blah` references to just be `blah` since it'll be in your scope.

Comment: welll angular added the controller bla as blaCtrl and var vm = this; for a reason and all guides that u can see recomend using those instead of having controller as it is and using $scope.  so the scope dosnt collide , with vm it wont collide and since this was added later on it seems abit odd to go back to the stuff angular had in the begining? why would they add something that abit longer if its worse then the stuff they already had ?

Comment: It's my understanding that controllerAs syntax's most value is for when you have nested scopes. You don't have nested scopes in this. As far as the vm=this issue, the author of that _style guide_ was using it primarily in services to keep state, and view models (hence the variable name, vm...). That said, do whatever you're comfortable with...but it appears the style guide has added more confusion than helped.